# Python/MySQL- Como obter o id de uma tabela fazendo comparação com duas diferentes

Tags: mysql, python

Tenho as duas seguintes tabelas como se pode ver na seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que por exemplo comparando o `username` (ao nível da sessão de cada utilizador) de cada uma retirar o seu id. Tenho usado a seguinte `query` mas não funciona `SELECT id_medico FROM medico UNION SELECT id_paciente FROM paciente WHERE username=%s`. O %s provém do `pyhton`, visto que estou a utilizar a `query` num página com `backend`em `pyhton`. A `query` completa é esta: `(SELECT id_medico FROM medico WHERE username=%s UNION SELECT id_paciente FROM paciente WHERE username=%s,(username,username))`. 
Até agora o id retornado é sempre o mesmo, 1.

P.S:Estou a utilizar o `pymysql` e `Flask`.

Comment: O que você quer é que quando `username` for `paciente1`, retorne o *id* 1 da tabela *pacientes*, se for `paciente2`, retorne o valor 2, mas caso seja `medico1`, retorne o *id* 1 da tabela *medicos*?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  exatamente isso

Comment: Veja http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6c1f/1. Assim os *ids* são retornados corretamente. Utilizei os *ids* 7 e 8 para os médicos para certificar-me que não está retornando errado. A única coisa é que assim não é possível saber de qual das tabelas o *id* está vindo. Você precisará saber se é paciente ou médico?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss desta maneira para o que eu queria já esta a funcionar e desde já agradeço. Mas para a futuro necessitava de saber, será que é possível ?

Comment: Sim. É possível. Vide resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme descrito na pergunta, você já possui a instrução que retorna o *id* conforme o valor do *username*, como subsequente:

```
select id_paciente as id from pacientes where username = "paciente1"
union select id_medico from medicos where username = "paciente1";
```

Porém, desta forma não é possível identificar a origem do valor retornado. Isto é, não há como saber se o *id* é referente a um paciente ou médico. Para isso, basta adicionar uma segunda coluna estática na seleção, diferindo o valor da seleção na tabela de pacientes e da tabela de médicos:

```
select id_paciente as id, "paciente" from pacientes where username = "paciente1"
union select id_medico, "medico" from medicos where username = "paciente1";
```

Veja que foi adicionada à seleção da tabela *pacientes* a coluna `"paciente"`, já à seleção da tabela *medicos* foi adicionada a coluna `"medico"`. Desta forma, o resultado possui uma segunda coluna, além do próprio *id*, que varia conforme a tabela selecionada.

Veja [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6c1f/7) o código em funcionamento.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Exatamente o que queria